# Restarting AFP Service / File Sharing Service

Tags: network, macos, sharing, afp

I'm using El Capitan (not Server) and every now and then me or other users can't access a shared (afp) folder or every mounted drive gets very slow.
If I enter the system preferences and navigate to sharing everything is extremely slow. After deactivating and reactivating file sharing in the sharing options everything works again (or restarting the OS)

First Question:
With OSX Server you can edit the AFP Settings from the Admin Console, but I'm not using OSX Server so I found /Library/Preferences/com.apple.AppleShareClient.plist 
where I can change different AFP Settings - does anybody know which setting could solve the problem I mentioned before?

Second Question: 
If the only way is to restart the Filesharing service / turn filesharing off and on again, does anybody know how I can automate this (like every night at 00:00 restart filesharing) I can not find the filesharing service to restart it via launchctl. Maybe anybody can give me an advice?

Thank you.

Comment: OSX services can be managed from the CLI as well (i.e. Using terminal). Regarding AFP: it's best to figure out the problem and solve it instead of leaving it be and restarting it all the time. Start with logs and activity monitor.

Comment: On El Capitan you cannot activate the AFP Logging via serveradmin console - do you know how to activate the afp logging anyway?

Comment: Yes, let me check and I'll post it here

Comment: This appears to be answered here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/272860/ensuring-file-sharing-stays-enabled-macos